# formatting console to have columns

Tags: java

I have to create an output with 5 columns
[Like This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2ST2.png)

The problem i've been having is that I keep getting errors (something about an array and a string) but we haven't covered arrays yet. This is what I have so far:

```
System.out.println("Game\tResult\t\t\tValue\tBooby Prize\t\tDescription");
System.out.printf("1",prize1Result,prize1Value(prize1BoobyPrize?"yes":"no"),prize1Desc);
```

*all the variables are correct (case etc.
The second line is causing the error, and it still needs to be formatted.

Comment: what errors, I see no errors listed

Comment: you need to understand the difference between `println()` and `printf()` : http://www.javawithus.com/tutorial/displaying-text-using-printf-method

Comment: Replace all the commas `,` with pluses `+` on the second line.

Comment: show me the javadoc where `System.out.printf()` takes a `String...vargs`?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with using tab is that it only brings the cursor to the next interval of 4 on a line. Instead you should use `String::format` and pad every string by the same amount

```
public static String padRight(String s, int n) {
     return String.format("%1$-" + n + "s", s);  
}

...

int paddingLength = 12;

System.out.println(
        padRight("Game", paddingLength) + 
        padRight("Result", paddingLength) + 
        padRight("Value", paddingLength) + 
        padRight("Booby Prize", paddingLength) + 
        padRight("Description", paddingLength)
);
System.out.println(
        padRight("1", paddingLength) + 
        padRight(prize1Result, paddingLength) + 
        padRight(prize1Value, paddingLength) + 
        padRight(prize1BoobyPrize?"yes":"no", paddingLength) + 
        padRight(prize1Desc, paddingLength)
);
```